# display latest tweet using api 1.1 in twig and symfony2

Tags: twitter, twig, symfony-2.3

I am trying to use Twitter API 1.1 with symfony2 and twig. So far I have succeed to pass all tweets as an array to the template but I am unable to get the latest tweet ONLY.

Everything works ok except the number or posts, so I am posting full code to help others also.

twitter functions

```
public function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

public function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

public function twitter_latest(){
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$oauth_access_token = "***";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "***";
$consumer_key = "***";
$consumer_secret = "***";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = $this->buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

// Make Requests
$header = array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);

return $twitter_data;
}
```

Controller:

```
/**
  * Index page 
  *
  */
public function indexAction() 
{
   $twitters = $this->twitter_latest();
   return $this->render('mwwqTestBundle:Main:index.html.twig', array("twitters" => $twitters));

}
```

Twig template:

```
<div id="mainTwitter">
   <ul id="twitter_update_list">
    {% for twitter in twitters %}  
        {{ twitter.text }}
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</div>
```

`{{ twitter.text[0] }}, {{ twitter[0].text }}, {{ twitter.text.[0] }}` are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to pass more than one tweet to the view if you only want to display one?

You could do something like this:

```
{% if loop.first %}
    {{ twitter.text }}
{% endif %}
```

**To change the count in the controller:**

Presumably you were just trying to change the url variable directly. I think you need to do something like the following. Sure I've seen it somewhere but can't find the original author:

```
public function twitter_latest($count = 1){
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$oauth_access_token = "***";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "***";
$consumer_key = "***";
$consumer_secret = "***";

$oauth = array( 'count' => $count,
                'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = $this->buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

// Make Requests
$header = array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url . '&count=' . $count,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);

return $twitter_data;
}
```

Comment: If I'd knew how, I would have already done it ! What about showing the 5th tweet ?

Comment: You can modify this to something like https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1 if you only want one to be returned - I can't think of a way to get a specific number back. I'll get back to you on it.

Comment: Haven't tested this but something like this: {% if loop.index == 5 %} should work.

Comment: API docs seem to say so https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline - although this is a max returned so might be a bit risky depending on which other options you set. How are you using it?

Comment: I have tried the ?count=1 but it does not work. You can see how I fully use it in my code posted above.

Comment: Added an example. Give it a shot and let me know how it goes.

Comment: your controller example doesn't seem to work... I am not sure why but it doesn't seem to accept the count parameter.

Comment: Could just make it a variable in the body. Doing it the way I mentioned in my answer would give more flexibility in using the controller in future but if you only ever want the latest tweet it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for twi in tweet|slice(0, 2)%}
<li>
<div>{{twi.text}}</div>
<small><strong>{{twi.created_at|date("m/d/Y")}}</strong></small>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.